# how to find the position of a character that sql had selected it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have stuck in a very complicated issue. 
I have defined a table in my database that includes these fields: id, title, category, little, flag, description.
for the Search part with a specific name in this table, I have written the below query in a function:

```
 $dsearch=mysql_real_escape_string($condition['title']);
"select id, title , category, little, flag, description 
            from    tbl_contents 
            where  title RLIKE  '[[:<:]]".$dsearch."[[:>:]]'
                   or 
                   description RLIKE  '[[:<:]]".$dsearch."[[:>:]]' 
            order by priority desc"
```

now here is my question: when "dsearch" has been found in the "description field" in this table, I want its "Position" to be given too. for example: if dsearch=Chance and Chance existed in the description field of one of the rows, it will return the position of Chance in that description field. 
will u plz help me??
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've introduces two more columns in the output, one for title position and one for description position. Remove the POSITION output column which you don't need.

```
"select id, title , category, little, flag, description,
           POSITION('$dsearch' IN title) AS pos_title,
           POSITION('$dsearch' IN description) AS pos_desc, 
        from    tbl_contents 
        where  title RLIKE  '[[:<:]]".$dsearch."[[:>:]]'
               or 
               description RLIKE  '[[:<:]]".$dsearch."[[:>:]]' 
        order by priority desc"
```

**Note** : give the `$dsearch` input to POSITION function as per your language syntax

Information regarding POSITION function

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_position

Comment: Good answer, but when referencing how functions work, I think it is better to use the actual documentation from the database:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_position.

Comment: @user1354678 Thanks a lot. I have run it but I have faced with another problem. the position that is returned, comes with html non-alphabetic characters. How can I use strip_tags in this query?

Comment: @user1354678 I have changed the query in this way : $sql = "select id, title , category, little,strip_tags('description') AS strip_desc , flag ,
          POSITION('$dsearch' IN title) AS pos_title,
                    POSITION('$dsearch' IN strip_desc) AS pos_desc
but I'm facing with error!